# What does "to trap in amber" mean and where does it come from?

Tags: meaning, etymology

> I guess that’s one of the reasons I do write here, **to trap in
>   amber** these states of emotion and experience in some way so I can
>   look back and ultimately think that I was writing a lot more in
>   [insert year here] even though I probably at that time felt I did a
>   lot more writing in some other era of my life

Comment: Unless this is a regional thing, this is not a common expression in English *(at least, I've never heard it)* - rather, it's a very clever metaphor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apart from the aspect of preservation described by the other answers, another aspect occurs to me -- that is the ability of amber to preserve and by virtue of its relative transparency, *still allow inspection*.

I feel this would apply to the emotions mentioned in the question. It would still be possible to *look back* (in the words of the quote) through the 'amber' and access the emotions.

Answer (score 21):

It means to preserve for perpetuity, or at least, a very long time.  Some creatures trapped in amber have been preserved for millions of years.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Haven't you seen [Jurassic Park](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107290/)? :-)

Insects *trapped in amber* have been found dating back to  the age of the dinosaurs. The point is that amber can preserve things extremely well dating back over millenia. [See this article](http://www.livescience.com/6316-life-trapped-amber-age-dinosaurs.html).

In the paragraph you wrote, the author is saying that they want to preserve their "states of emotion and experience" and not forget them.